# How to write a variable to a file on a new line every time?

Tags: python, file, variables

I am trying to put a variable in to a file and have it go on a new line every time. For example, `file.write(variablehere)`

This has already been asked with how to write it as a string like `file.write(stringhere)` and to do it that way, you just do "/n" but that doesn't work with variables for some reason.

I've tried this as:

```
file.write(variable/n)
file.write('variable/n')
file.write(variable + '/n')
```

None of those worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a forward slash `/n` and you need to use a backslash `\n`.

Comment: (Probably should have caught this error as it's pretty small) Thanks for the answer, it worked! Will accept your answer as soon as it allows me to.

Comment: Cool...sometimes it's just a second set of eyes that's helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You could, if you want skip the `\n` business for your specific problem if you use the following

```
print(variable, file=somefilehandle)
```

The you can change the separators using `sep` parameter which defaults to `" "` and `end` which defaults to `"\n"`.

Comment: This is the best answer. Here `variable` can be any (printable) type instead of forcing it to be a string.